# перевод значений enum в select ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, i18n, erb

Мой select принимает элементами списка значения enum,объявленного в модели.
Select:

```
<div id="window" >
    <%= f.label :Повторяется %>
    <%= f.select :repeat_interval,options_for_select(Event.repeat_intervals.keys, @event.repeat_interval)%>
  </div>
```

Модель:

```
enum repeat_interval: [ :not_repeat, :week, :month, :year ]
```

Сейчас элементами списка select являются ключи repeat_interval, хотелось бы выводить элементы списка в селекторе на русском языке, не трогая ключи repeat_interval.
Как мне это организовать, может есть какой-то гем, слышал про enum-help, но пока не смог с ним разобраться.